# Is it possible to send location data silently from the iphone (with users agreement ofcourse)?

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation

I was wondering if it possible to create an application that will send my 9 year old's iPhone location let's say each 30 minutes, even when the iPhone is not active.
If not, then is it possible to send it each time he uses his phone?

Comment: if app is not active the iphone will kill it after 30 minutes or so.
there are exception when the app download from the internet, or when the gps is on, but what you need is sending information throught the internet "uploading" i think that 30 minutes limit apply

Answer (score 2):

Why not using an existing solution?

http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/find-my.html

See find my friends - it has also parental restrictions. This is excatly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `startMonitoringForReigion:desiredAccuracy:`. This function will allow you to set the iPhone to notify your app anytime a defined boundary is crossed. When you receive this notification, I believe you can send that info to a server or wherever.

That said, if monitoring your child's location is what you want, you'll have great luck with the Find My Friends app from Apple.